# How can I display a logo for a landing page in a nav bar in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put the image on the far left of the navigation bar but whenever I do the image just doesn't show up and is not there, but when I try and put the image in the footer or a paragraph it displays just fine.

I tried to put the image in other tags and it worked just fine, its just that I want the image to be inside the header.

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background-color: rgb(40, 44, 52);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#Logo img {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(33, 37, 43);
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#navbar li {
  float: right;
}

#navbar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.buttons {
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#Logo {
  font-size: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /* Adjust the margin as needed */
  margin-left: 0;
  /* Reset the right margin */
  text-align: left;
}

#Services {
  font-size: 3.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 80px;
}

#Help {
  font-size: 3.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.mains {
  font-size: 1em;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -260px;
  margin-left: 750px;
}

#joinButton {
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: RGB(33, 150, 243);
}

#aboutUs {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 250px;
  /* Adjust the value as needed */
}

.mainContent {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-top: 30px;
  /* Adjust the value as needed */
}

footer {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 20px;
  /* Adjust the value as needed */
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 10px;
  /* Adjust the value as needed */
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  /* Adjust the value as needed */
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Practice</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul id="navbar">
      <button class="buttons"><li><a href="#services">Services</a></li></button>
      <button class="buttons"><li><a href="#about">About</a></li></button>
      <button class="buttons"><li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li></button>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <header id="Logo">
    <img src="PlanetCodeLogo.jpg" alt="Planet Code Logo">
  </header>
  <header class="theslogan" id="Slogan">
    The #1 Coding website in America!
  </header>
  <main id="aboutUs">About Us</main>
  <div class="mainbuttonmanager">
    <main class="mainContent" id="mainText">
      Reminagining The World Of Programing<br>one script at a time.
    </main>
  </div>
  <footer>
    Welcome to Planet Code, the ultimate online destination for coding <br>enthusiasts of all levels! Our mission is to demystify the world of <br>programming by offering a diverse range of interactive courses,<br> expert-led tutorials, and hands-on projects.
    Whether you’re taking<br>your first steps into code or looking to refine your skills, Planet Code <br>provides a supportive community and the resources you need to succeed.<br> Join us and start your journey to becoming a coding master today!
  </footer>

  <button class="buttons" id="joinButton">Join us today!</button>
  <img src="giphy.gif">
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `margin-top: -260px` style is hiding the image whenever you put it in the navigation bar. You're able to see it when it's in the footer or paragraph because the margin top from those places are more than 260px.

Additional:
This `margin-top: -260px` and `margin-left: 750px` affects every image in your website because you added them in the `img` tag, a better approach would be to add these styles to an id or class and attach to any image you want.

```
img {
    display:block;
    margin-top: -260px; // remove this
    margin-left: 750px; // remove this
}
```

Comment: Okay, that seems to fix the issue but one more question is that for the image when I display it the whole navigation bar gets expanded how do I lock the navigation bar's size and display the logo?

Comment: You can add width to the navbar to lock the navbar size but a better approach would be to reduce the size(width, height) of your image.

Answer (score 0):

I mean you really need a working example here to point out the real issue; but, one thing I noticed is you shouldn't be using negative margins.

```
img {
    display:block;
    margin-top: -260px; <---
    margin-left: 750px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a navbar, with an image on the left and the links on the right. Note, that I have removed many of the unnecessary HTML elements, this simplifies your CSS and makes you code more readable with the addition of reserving the semantic HTML elements (like button) for their actual purpose

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

body{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    background-color:  rgb(40, 44, 52);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 4rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.navbar-links {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-links a {
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav img {
  width: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="https://placehold.co/400" alt="placeholder">
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <a href="#services">Services</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```